# How to find max number of As Substring in a given string

Tags: string, substring

**JAVA**

Please Help me with the code. It is showing n-1 as output for number of As in a Sub-string of given string. For example, consider a string "AAABBBBBAAAAAA", in this string max number of Sub-string of As is 6 but my code is displaying 6-1=5.

````
{
    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        String str=s.nextLine();
        int size=str.length();
        int count=0,max=0;
        
        for(int i=0;i<=size-1;i++)
        {
            if(str.charAt(i)=='A')
            {
                count++;
                max=count;
            }
            else
            {
                count--;
            }
        }
        System.out.print(max);                 
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I think you are looking for is this

```
String str="AAABBBBBAAAAAA";
int size=str.length();
int count=0,max=0;

for(int i=0;i<=size-1;i++)
{
    if(str.charAt(i)=='A')
    {
        count++;
        if(count > max) max = count;
    }
    else
    {
        count=0;
    }
}
System.out.print(max);
```

What this code is doing is every time it sees that an `A` is not present, it will reset the count. Also, the max only updates when the count of `A`'s is more than the previous substring. In this way, you will get the maximum length of substring.

I have used a hard-coded string, but you can modify it the way you want.

Comment: i tried with i<=size but it throws array out of bound exception

Comment: Yeah I am sorry that was not the problem, I have updated my answer and hopefully that helps. @ShubhamsinghThakur

Comment: Thank you @Mr.Furqan Saeed before only 6 out of 8 cases were getting passed now all the 8 test cases passed. Thanks for the help 